# Building a Progress Meter which aligns Steps and a Meter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working to create a progress meter which has 4 steps:

**25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% completion.**

The goal is to pass the component the percentageComplete and then have the component render the progress meter where the width of the bar represents percentage complete and the step bubbles are activated based on if the percentage completion matches the 25, 50, 75 and 100% thresholds.

[image]

The above is what I would eventually expect to see if we passed ~80% to the component.. Currently this is what is rendering for 75% which is not desired. It should be:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 288px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 12px;
    background: #E6E6E7;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.container:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 4px;
    background: blue;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 75%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: width .2s ease;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.step:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ececec;
}

.p25:after,
.p50:after,
.p75:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step p25"></div>
  <div class="step p50"></div>
  <div class="step p75"></div>
  <div class="step 100p"></div>
</div>
```

If you play with the snippet, you'll notice changing the width of

```
.container:after {
 width: ___%;
}
```

does not render as desired.

Any suggestions on how I can get this ui component to render as desired by simply passing a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're starting at 25% instead of zero, you need need start at `-25%` and add to that. You also need to take into account the width of the step.

```
width: calc(-25% + xx% + (24px * yy));
```

- `xx` is the percent desired
- `yy` is the step offset

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 288px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 12px;
  background: #E6E6E7;
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: calc(-25% + 50% + (24px * 1));
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: width .2s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.step:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ececec;
}

.p25:after,
.p50:after,
.p75:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step p25"></div>
  <div class="step p50"></div>
  <div class="step p75"></div>
  <div class="step 100p"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: love this direction... what is yy?

Comment: yy is the step offset (aka your circles) 0 = first circle; 1 = second circle, etc.. I couldn't figure a way to automatically calculate that one in pure css though. but you would want to take it's percentage and a modules to figure it out somehow.

Comment: what should I be calculating. The # of circles that should be active?

Comment: if your above 25% it would be `(24px * 1)` above 50% would be `(24px * 2)` and above 75% would be `(24px * 3)`

Comment: Thanks, I love the idea but it doesn't seem to work... If the percentage is equal to 100 this is what occurs: `    width: calc(-25% + 100% + (24px * 4));` --- is that expected? That width grows past the container...

Comment: Sorry, my offsets were wrong, 25% it would be `(24px * 0)` above 50% would be `(24px * 1)` and above 75% would be `(24px * 2)` 100% would be `(24px * 3)`

Comment: amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, where you can control in JS the width value of track.

```css
.track{
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 288px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 12px;
    background: #E6E6E7;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.step:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ececec;
}

.p:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="track" style="width: 80%"></div>
  <div class="step p"></div>
  <div class="step p"></div>
  <div class="step p"></div>
  <div class="step p"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea with less of code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin:20px;
  width: 288px;
  height:50px;
  --i:100%;
  --p:calc(var(--i) - 56px);
  background:
  /*The 4 circles*/
  radial-gradient(circle at center,#E6E6E7 50%,transparent 53%) 100% 0/ 40px 100%,
  radial-gradient(circle at center,blue 50%,transparent 53%) calc(2*100% / 3) 0/ 40px 100%,
  radial-gradient(circle at center,blue 50%,transparent 53%) calc(100% / 3) 0/ 40px 100%,
  radial-gradient(circle at center,blue 50%,transparent 53%) 0 0/ 40px 100%,
  /*The progress bar*/
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 20px 50%/var(--p) 20% no-repeat,
  /*The bottom Bar*/
  linear-gradient(#E6E6E7,#E6E6E7) center/calc(100% - 20px) 30% no-repeat;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="container" style="--i:75%">
</div>
<div class="container" style="--i:50%">
</div>
<div class="container" style="--i:25%">
</div>
```